# chanaging standard_name and long_name with NCO

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I calculated the [potential temperaure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_temperature) from a NetCDF file. I would like to change `standard_name` and `long_name` with `NCO`.
I have tried some commands without sucess, e.g.:

```
> ncatted -a name,Temperature,o,c,"Potential_Temperature" pt_19891020-19891022.nc

ncatted: ERROR File contains no variables or groups that match name Temperature so attribute name cannot be changed

> ncrename -a air_temperature,air_potential_temperature -a Temperature,Potential_Temperature pt_19891020-19891022.nc

ncrename: ERROR Required attribute 'air_temperature' not present in group '/'.
HINT: If attribute presence is intended to be optional, then prefix attribute name with the period character '.', e.g., .air_temperature. With this syntax ncrename would succeed even when no variables or groups contain the attribute. If the attribute is intended to be renamed only in a specific variable, then prepend the variable name plus an at-sign '@' to the attribute name, e.g., var_nm@att_nm. If attribute presence is required only for root group (i.e., a global attribute), then prefix attribute name with "global" and an at-sign, e.g., global@att_nm. If attribute presence is required for all groups, then prefix attribute name with "group" and an at-sign, e.g., group@att_nm.
```

Current file attributes:

```
$ cdo showattsvar pt_19891020-19891022.nc 
 pt:
   standard_name = "air_temperature"
   long_name = "Temperature"
   units = "K"
   missing_value = -32767
```

Desired attributes:

```
 pt:
   standard_name = "air_potential_temperature"
   long_name = "Potential_Temperature"
   units = "K"
   missing_value = -32767
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are attributes so `ncatted` is the correct tool, and the documentation is [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#xmp_ncatted) with examples of the correct syntax:

```
ncatted -a standard_name,pt,o,c,air_potential_temperature -a long_name,pt,o,c,Potential_temperature pt_19891020-19891022.nc
```